# Best way to store data in MongoDB for real-estate project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am working on real estate project using MEAN stack. I have concern of about getting data and manipulating it if we store in any random way. So please let me know the best way to store data . Business requirement is as follows

In this project we have

```
1.Properties
2.Each property has Towers 
3.Each Tower has Floors (with floor plans)
3.Each Floor has Flats
4.Each Flat is an inventory (with status available, sold, blocked, in-active) 
5.Each Flat has configurations like no.of BHK, carpet area, built area, super built area so on
```

I very confused with how to design the collections as these are interdependent on each other and we are using Mongo DB as database. So please help me out?. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a relational database like `postgreSQL` for this situation, but if you want to use `mongodb` you can use `populate` because you have many relation between collection, maybe you need to many reports that want to merge collection together.

when you use populate you need to update two or more collections, but getting data from multiple collection is very easier.

you can check the [populate documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).
it's a good article how to use [populate](https://zellwk.com/blog/mongoose-population/) in `node.js`